# makemigrations not identifying database changes

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

I'm using `django`,now I renamed a python file from `custom_fields` to `fields` and change a Model class,and the Model class is using a field comes from `fields` file,but when I run

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

such error exists:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/Users/smy/wuque/projects/LinuxChat/Server/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
File "/Users/smy/wuque/projects/LinuxChat/Server/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 342, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/Users/smy/wuque/projects/LinuxChat/Server/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/Users/smy/wuque/projects/LinuxChat/Server/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/Users/smy/wuque/projects/LinuxChat/Server/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 65, in handle
    loader = MigrationLoader(None, ignore_no_migrations=True)
File "/Users/smy/wuque/projects/LinuxChat/Server/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
File "/Users/smy/wuque/projects/LinuxChat/Server/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 170, in build_graph
    self.load_disk()
File "/Users/smy/wuque/projects/LinuxChat/Server/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 105, in load_disk
    migration_module = import_module("%s.%s" % (module_name, migration_name))
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
File "/Users/smy/wuque/projects/LinuxChat/Server/LinuxChatServer/Server/migrations/0005_auto_20151215_1223.py", line 5, in <module>
    import Server.custom_fields
ImportError: No module named custom_fields
```

I don't know how to solve this error,so I try to delete `migrates` folder,but when I run above command again,nothing changed can be detected,even I modify Model class again.Just show:

```
No changes detected.
```

Now I can't modify database table,anyone can tell me how to solve this problem?thanks!

Comment: Is the python file just a file full of your custom fields? This won't have any affect on the database itself

Comment: I would try to first to change the name fields to another name like fields0. Sometimes in python you may use names that are protected for other functions. The second thing I would try is to remove the database and start again: `python manage.py syncdb` then makemigrations and migrate...

Comment: @Sayse,but the Model class is using a field from `custom_fileds`,now called `fields`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is the first time you are migrating that app you have to use:

```
manage.py makemigrations myappname
```

Once you do that you can do:

```
manage.py migrate
```

Running makemigrations in the project folder means it will look to update all the tables related to all the apps included in settings.py for the project. Once you include it, makemigrations will automatically include the app (this saves a lot of work so you don't have to run makemigrations app_name for every app in your project/site).

If you confused any of these steps, read the migration files. Change them to correct your schema or remove unwanted files but don't forget to change next migration file's dependencies part .

Comment: maybe these migrations file has been deleted,now any model changes can be detected, so I run above command,it hints me:`no changes detected`,this is my current problem:I can't modify database table as my `Model` class described.

Comment: i think your makemigrations files corrupted or unable to read. so i suggest you to delete database and makemigrations files expect __init__ file. and  create new database and do migrations.

Comment: Yes,this can work,I have tried and works well,but I don't know why cause my problem.

Answer (score 2):

`makemigrations` is done to apply changes that will directly affect the underlying structure of a database.

Renaming your python file will have no affect whatsoever on the database since the *type* of field hasn't changed and thus it won't have any affect on the database. All you end up seeing is a different import in your python file.

Comment: My question has been updated.The renamed file contains a custom Field class,which is used in one Model class.

Comment: @FireSun - Exactly, but all you've done is renamed what would need to be imported, the actual *field* hasn't changed at all

Comment: @FireSun - Update `0005_auto_20151215_1223.py` to use the correct import (and anywhere else)

Comment: @FireSun - Then the problem should be resolved?.. You probably either need to remake them with `makemigrations` or you need to retrieve them again and repeat my previous comment

Comment: No,after done,any changes can't be detected,so I can't modify database table,this is my current problem.

Comment: @FireSun - But there aren't any changes to detect, you havent changed the database, you may need to rerun the initial migration again as shown in Maneesh Nandan's answer but that wasn't what your question was asking about

Comment: I don't know why it can't detect my changed about Model class,but I changed its fields actually,now I delete the database and run `migrate` it works well and `migrates` folder has been created again automatically.

Comment: @FireSun - What do you expect to have changed?

Comment: Because I changed some fileds of one Model class,so I expect run `makemigrations` commands can detect this,and I run `migrate` command to sync database table,but it can't detect the change.

Comment: @FireSun - Most likely cause is that since you've remade the initial migration, the field is now the type you're expecting it to be already. Although this is venturing in to something that is a separate question